Is Unity Legacy/Diffuse shader almost as efficient as Mobile/Diffuse shader (for mobile apps)?
I am developing mobile apps. I know that Mobile shaders are the best options for mobile apps in terms of fast performance.
However, I purchased 1 Unity asset, which only works with Legacy/Diffuse shader. When I tried to replace the Legacy/Diffuse shader with Mobile/Diffuse shader, all the colors of the object turned "white" incorrectly.
Do you know if Legacy/Diffuse shader is almost as fast as Mobile/Diffuse shader for mobile apps ?
Will the performance not be significantly negatively impacted if I have to use Legacy/Diffuse shader for mobile apps ?

The developer of this asset says that Legacy/Diffuse is almost the same as Mobile/Diffuse. But, I think he creates and sells this asset. So, his answer may not be very impartial.

The best way to answer this question is by profiling. It might be that this shader is significantly more expensive, but in ways that don't matter for your application (i.e. you had headroom, or your main bottleneck is elsewhere). Or it might turn out that it's about the same cost, but it uses resources that are already the bottleneck in your game scenes / on your target hardware, so your game runs slower with it while our tests might show no appreciable slowdown at all. So there's really no substitute for testing it and getting direct, empirical evidence tailored to your use case.

@DMGregory, Thanks for your suggestion. Let me test.
